# Codeigniter Create a database and table outside of config/database.php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am attempting to create a database and table for each customer registered from my `codeigniter` site, i am looking at the `dbforge` documentation and tried below code.

but error appeared, i want to make it dynamic for each customer so putting it on config/database.php is not available is there a way to prevent this?
i am new with codeigniter not sure if below code is also correct.

> `You have specified an invalid database connection group
>   (customer_LYWA) in your config/database.php file.`

```
   public function create_customer_database($code){

        $database = $this->dbutil->database_exists('customer_'.$code);


        if($database){

            return "";

        }else{

            $this->dbforge->create_database('customer_'.$code);

        $fields = array(
                        'blog_id' => array(
                                                 'type' => 'INT',
                                                 'constraint' => 5,
                                                 'unsigned' => TRUE,
                                                 'auto_increment' => TRUE
                                          ),
                        'blog_title' => array(
                                                 'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                                                 'constraint' => '100',
                                          ),
                        'blog_author' => array(
                                                 'type' =>'VARCHAR',
                                                 'constraint' => '100',
                                                 'default' => 'King of Town',
                                          ),
                        'blog_description' => array(
                                                 'type' => 'TEXT',
                                                 'null' => TRUE,
                                          ),
                );

$this->dbforge->add_field($fields);

$this->dbforge->add_key('blog_id', TRUE);
// gives PRIMARY KEY (blog_id)

$this->dbforge->add_key('blog_title');
// gives KEY (blog_title)
$otherdb = $this->load->database('customer_'.$code, TRUE);
$this->dbforge->create_table('blog');

             return "created";

        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a table for each customer.

With that, I think you are confusing databases with tables. databases **contain** tables, so you will need to connect to the correct database in **config/database.php**, and use your script to create tables inside that database.

You don't need to create a new database for each customer. That would make things 100 times harder than they should be, and will be very hard to maintain.